# Why is there no getFilesDir(type) in android?

Tags: android

There exists `getExternalFilesDir(type)` where type can be `null`, `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, etc., but `getFilesDir()` just returns the internal storage version of `getExternalFilesDir(null)`. Are you supposed to neatly categorize your files for external, but not for internal? So, why doesn't `getFilesDir(type)` exist?

Comment: getFilesDir() is both a much older API, and one which accesses a normally *private* medium - such that if you make a mess, it's only your own problem.  In contrast, getExternalFilesDir() returns a location on potentially shared storage and is an API added *after* there was both some experience with apps that did so, and some desire to move away from raw storage to categorized stores which might someday be individually (rather than globally) shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the internal storage is pretty much locked-down and private for each app, the external locations were traditionally both inconsistently located and globally readable. To manage the chaos, some helper methods were added in Android 2.2 (Froyo).

[Environmant.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) is for the location where items of that *type* are to be shared across apps. Files written here will remain after the app is uninstalled.

[getExternalFilesDir (String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) if for the location where items of that *type* that are to be private to the app and subsequently deleted when the app is uninstalled.

The latter was presumably added to maintain symmetry with the former. At the time, no analogous method was added to compliment [getFilesDir ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), which had been available since Android 1.0. My speculation is that Google didn't see much point in recommending a structure for a location that going forward would typically hold fairly a small number of files.